# Responding to Events of Dynamically added Controls

Tags: vba, excel

I was asked for an example of a class to wrap dynamically added controls as I suggested in this [Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205212/171419).  Although it is out of the context of a Code Review, I thought that it would make an interesting post.

I'm looking for feedback on not only "How to improve my code" but also "How to better explain my code".

---

### Basic Custom Control Pattern

[image: Basic Custom Control Pattern]

### Userform1: Userform

- CustomControls:Collection - Used to store the CustomControls in memory.
- AddCustomControls() - Add new controls to Userform1, links them to a New CustomControl.  The New CustomControl is then added to the CustomControls collection.
- CustomCombo_Change(Item:CustomContol): This public method is called by a CustomControl when the CustomControls.Combo Change event is fired.

### CustomControl: Class

[image: Withevents Demo Image]

- WithEvents Combo:MsForms.ComboBox - Using WithEvents allows the class to receive the controls events
- Form:UserForm1 - The class stores a reference to the parent Userform so that it can trigger custom Userform events.  Typically a references to either the class of to one of the classes controls is passed back to the parent form.

---

### Advanced Custom Control Pattern

This pattern has the userform Implement an Interface.  The custom class references the userform's Interface instead of the actual userform. In this way, the Custom class can be used with any other class or userform that Implements the Interface.

[image: advanced custom control pattern]

---

### Advanced Pattern Demo

This code applies the Advanced Pattern to this post: [Loop through different controls and enabled the state of the whole group VBA]
 ([Loop through different controls and enabled the state of the whole group VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205096/171419)).

Download the demo: [dynamic-control-rows.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wImzlPIHT85pQRCs1GDBFWv8NlQII_xk). Note: The workbook also contains the TemplateForm that I used to generate most of the code for the controls.

### IItemsForm:Interface

```
Public Sub ItemRowUpdated(Item As ItemRow)
End Sub
```

### ItemsForm:UserForm

```
Option Explicit
Implements IItemsForm
Private ItemRows As New Collection

Private Sub btnAddRows_Click()
    Dim Item As New ItemRow
    Item.Init FrameItems, Me
    Item.cboItem.List = Array("Jumper", "Shirt", "Trouser")
    ItemRows.Add Item
    SpaceItems
End Sub

Private Sub SpaceItems()
    Const PaddingTop As Double = 5
    Dim Top As Double
    Dim Item As ItemRow
    Top = PaddingTop

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To ItemRows.Count
        Set Item = ItemRows(n)
        Item.ckItemNo.Caption = n
        Item.Top = Top
        Top = Top + Item.Frame.Height + PaddingTop
    Next
    EnableItems
End Sub

Private Sub EnableItems()
    Dim Item As ItemRow, PreviousItem As ItemRow
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Enabled As Boolean
    Enabled = True
    For n = 2 To ItemRows.Count
        Set PreviousItem = ItemRows(n - 1)
        Set Item = ItemRows(n)

        Item.Enabled = PreviousItem.cboItem.Value <> vbNullString
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteSelectedRows_Click()
    Dim Item As New ItemRow
    Dim n As Long

    For n = ItemRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = ItemRows(n)
        If Item.ckItemNo.Value = True Then
            ItemRows.Remove n
            FrameItems.Controls.Remove Item.Frame.Name
        End If
    Next

    SpaceItems
End Sub

Private Sub IItemsForm_ItemRowUpdated(Item As ItemRow)
    EnableItems
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    btnAddRows_Click
End Sub
```

### ItemRow: Class

```
Option Explicit
Public Form As IItemsForm

Public Frame As MSForms.Frame
Public ckItemNo As MSForms.CheckBox
Public WithEvents cboItem As MSForms.ComboBox
Public txtQty As MSForms.TextBox
Public txtUnitPrice As MSForms.TextBox
Public txtSubTotal As MSForms.TextBox
Public optIn As MSForms.OptionButton
Public optOut As MSForms.OptionButton
Public txtComments As MSForms.TextBox

Public Sub Init(TargetFrame As MSForms.Frame, TargetForm As IItemsForm)
    Set Form = TargetForm
    Set Frame = TargetFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
    Frame.Height = 24
    Frame.Width = 630
    With Frame.Controls

        Set ckItemNo = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
        With ckItemNo
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 6
            .Width = 57
            .Height = 18
        End With

        Set cboItem = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
        With cboItem
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 78
            .Width = 120
            .Height = 18
        End With

        Set txtQty = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtQty
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 204
            .Width = 30
            .Height = 18
        End With

        Set txtUnitPrice = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtUnitPrice
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 240
            .Width = 60
            .Height = 18
        End With

        Set txtSubTotal = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtSubTotal
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 306
            .Width = 60
            .Height = 18
        End With

        Set optIn = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.OptionButton.1")
        With optIn
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 378
            .Width = 27
            .Height = 18
            .Caption = "IN"
        End With

        Set optOut = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.OptionButton.1")
        With optOut
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 408
            .Width = 38.25
            .Height = 18
            .Caption = "OUT"
        End With

        Set txtComments = .Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        With txtComments
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 456
            .Width = 168
            .Height = 18
        End With

    End With

End Sub

Public Property Get Top() As Double
    Top = Frame.Top
End Property

Public Property Let Top(ByVal Value As Double)
    Frame.Top = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Enabled() As Boolean
    Enabled = Frame.Enabled
End Property

Public Property Let Enabled(ByVal Value As Boolean)
    Frame.Enabled = Value

    Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each Ctrl In Frame.Controls
        Ctrl.Enabled = Frame.Enabled
    Next
End Property

Private Sub cboItem_Change()
    Form.ItemRowUpdated Me
End Sub
```

[image: Advanced Pattern Demo]

---

### Addendum

@sifar pointed out that after deleting the first row the second row will not enable itself.   The frame scrollbar also needed to be set to `fmScrollBarsVertical` and its `ScrollHeight` set when there are more items then can be seen.

### Code FIx

```
Private Sub SpaceItems()
    Const PaddingTop As Double = 5
    Dim Top As Double
    Dim Item As ItemRow
    Top = PaddingTop

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To ItemRows.Count
        Set Item = ItemRows(n)
        Item.ckItemNo.Caption = n
        Item.Top = Top
        Top = Top + Item.Frame.Height + PaddingTop
    Next
    EnableItems
    Top = Top - PaddingTop
    With Me.FrameItems
        .ScrollBars = IIf(Top > .Height, fmScrollBarsVertical, fmScrollBarsNone)
        .ScrollHeight = Top
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub EnableItems()
    Dim Item As ItemRow, PreviousItem As ItemRow
    Dim n As Long

    If ItemRows.Count > 0 Then ItemRows(1).Enabled = True

    For n = 2 To ItemRows.Count
        Set PreviousItem = ItemRows(n - 1)
        Set Item = ItemRows(n)
        Item.Enabled = PreviousItem.cboItem.Value <> vbNullString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the above this will help me a lot. Much appreciated you taking the time to write all this valuable knowledge.

Comment: Can i ask you in the above example if you fill 5 rows of data and close excel down and reopen then will it still have the 5 rows of data there or will this be reseted and start a new one? Probably somewhare in the form needs a drop down to select a staff and then that will trigger a procedure that will pre populate data that is in excel table? Also is there a way to add a placeholder just to hint to the user what to put in each field?

Comment: i am trying to do the above but excel is crashing on this line `Set Frame = TargetFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")` for some reason. I've checked the controls to be the same name as your example but still it's not working. Correct me if i'm wrong but you can add your template to any frame on a userform right? My form is already on screen is when i press the add row button and goes in the public init it then crashes.

Comment: I am not home at the moment but will forward it across as soon as I get home. Weird part is I have your example running there and yours still work for some reason. Probably I’ve missed something. By Implements IItemsForm you mean on the userform code base to write the statement on the top where option explicit is right. If so then I definitely have that but probably there is something else that I am missing.

Comment: @TinMan sorry for the late comment...the only issues i see is that the frame or the form doesn't have vertical scrollbar, so new itemrows added do not appear. Also, if i delete the top enabled item by ticking it, the form becomes useless as the other itemrows remain disabled and cannot be selected for use. Is there a workaround or addition you can make to your code to tackle these issues?

Comment: @TinMan  If i comment out this line, it enables each itemrow that is added: `Item.Enabled = PreviousItem.cboItem.Value <> vbNullString`

Comment: @TinMan sorry, i was using my mobile in the dark while outside home. Can enabling the vertical scrollbar resolve the visibility issue faced while adding multiple itemrows? Or does it need to be coded in the class itself?

Comment: @TinMan i added your changes. Something is wrong! if i add a couple of itemrows and then delete the top enabled itemrows, i am left a bunch of disabled itemrows which i cannot delete. see [https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uaRRRwogRMKLRLTDZDeMWG6f8c3l4dt/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uaRRRwogRMKLRLTDZDeMWG6f8c3l4dt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @sifar  I updated the code and my workbook link.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @TinMan excellent! I only removed `Top = Top - PaddingTop` as i needed padding. Looks great.

Comment: @sifar I'm glad to see this post being used.